# How to run my snap application on startup

Tags: startup, snap, autostart, nodejs, electron

I have a snapcraft application build on top of electronJs.
I would like that application to run on startup.

I tried to directly drop a  `app_name.desktop` file inside the current user config/autostart path but I was not able to do it from within my code, I got a right access issue which means I am not allowed to perform such action. I noticed inside the snap folder there is a `.config`. I thought that dropping my `.desktop` file there should work but nothing.

Is there a way to run my snap application on startup? Is there a command I should add to my `.yml` file or is there a way to do it directly from my code?

Here is my config

```
[Desktop Entry]
 Type=Application
 Terminal=false
 Exec=/snap/bin/rightplayer
 X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
 StartupNotify=false
 Name=myapp
```

Comment: @pomsky i just did it

Comment: Try changing `Exec=snap run myapp` to `Exec=/full/path/to/the/executable`.

Comment: Doesnt work. That was the first thing I did. In fact I tried that command manually and it works. But When I try to do it whithin my code I get a right access issue. Seems I cant do it. Then I decided to add that config inside snap config itself but it doesnt work either

Comment: Maybe read thru here, see what's up  https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-to-autostart-a-snap-of-a-desktop-application/2449

Answer (score 11):

- Get the exact path of the snap location you wish to execute. You can do that by executing the following in the **`Terminal`** -

  ```
  which nameOfSnap
  /usr/bin/nameOfSnap    #copy this path
  ```
- Search for "Startup Applications" from the Launcher 
  [image]
- Click on add. Paste the path in the `command` textbox. You can provide any name, comment. 
  [image]
- Click on "Add" at the bottom and the snap will be added to your startup applications.

**Reference** - [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)